# How to make a page scroll horizontally

Tags: html

How can I make a page scroll horizontally when the page is resized? I have a menu bar at the top of the page, and when the window is resized, the browser automatically wraps the line, which makes the bar look awkward. How can I make the page *not* automatically wrap?

Comment: Code.  Give us your code????!!!!!  Sorry.  Yeah, so we'd need to see your code to answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your page to be a static size so that your navigation does not get wrapped to the next line. This concept would violate the the rules of responsive design. A better alternative is using @media queries and linking CSS for handheld devices to handle the wrapping.

This said, you can make your body a specific width in CSS:

```
body {
  width:1024px;
}
```